# Пример js sortable

Tags: javascript, sortable

Нужен пример подобного поведения - плагин или существующая реализация (jQueryUI Sortable работает не совсем так, например)
когда плейсхолдер в сортируемом списке "приклеен" к самому перемещаемому элементу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]